# Chartjs - reverse animation in bar chart

Tags: animation, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm using Chartjs to render a bar chart and, in this case, I'm using the reverse option - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/api/interfaces/CoreScaleOptions.html - to render lower values on the top and higher on the bottom.
Everything works OK but the default animation is still rendered from the lowest to the highest value (in this case, from top to bottom), which is the opposite from what we need. Is there some option to also reverse the animations?

Thanks